# How can I join two tables and count occurences for a value?

Tags: sql-server

I have these tables:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Word] 
(
    [WordId]        UNIQUEIDENTIFIER DEFAULT (newid()) NOT NULL,
    [Name]          VARCHAR (20)     NOT NULL,
    [Ascii]         AS               (ascii([Name])) PERSISTED,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([WordId] ASC)
);

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[WordForm] 
(
    [WordFormId]   UNIQUEIDENTIFIER DEFAULT (newid()) NOT NULL,
    [WordId]       UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,
    [SourceId]     INT              DEFAULT ((1)) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_WordForm] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([WordFormId] ASC),
);
```

Is there a way that I can join these two tables and show a count for each different ascii value where the `SourceId` in the second table has a value of 1?

To return something like:

```
a  25
b  30
c  22
d  10
```

Comment: That's either uber basic & simple or very unclear. Provide sample data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean something like this:

```
SELECT W.Ascii, COUNT(*) AS [Count] FROM Word W
INNER JOIN WordForm WF
ON W.WordId = WF.WordId
WHERE W.WordId = 1
GROUP BY W.Ascii
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use inner join on your select statement...

```
SELECT W.Ascii, COUNT(1)
FROM
    [dbo].[Word] W
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[WordForm] WF
        ON WF.WordId = W.WordId
WHERE
    WF.SourceId = 1
GROUP BY
    W.Ascii
```